i need to make a map call inside another map call and set both array items as template literals inside the value of an option for a datalist
so im trying to get the options for a datalist input and i have an object that looks like this
{
    "name": "Barbarian",
    "multi_classing": {
        "prerequisites": [
            {
                "ability_score": {
                    "index": "str",
                    "name": "STR",
                    "url": "/api/ability-scores/str"
                },
                "minimum_score": 13
            }
        ],
        "proficiencies": [
            {
                "index": "shields",
                "name": "Shields",
                "url": "/api/proficiencies/shields"
            },
            {...more stuff}
        ]
    }
},
{...More stuff}
]

i need to populate a datalist so that for barbarian it says Barbarian- Requires 13 STR and so on for every other class. this is what i was thinking, but even looking at it i know im way off.
multiClassData.map((className, i) => {
                            className.multi_classing.prerequisites.map((requirment, j) => {
                                return(
                                    <option
                                        key={i}
                                        value={`${className.name}- Requires ${requirment.minimum_score} ${requirment.ability_score.name}`}/>
                                )
                            })
                        })

how can i get the nested object array to get mapped on the option element?

seems like you are doing it correctly, what's your issue?

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') this throws on the nested map. and even if it didnt, wouldnt it have an option for every requirement, instead of all the appropriate requirements on one option?

something like this may be what you're trying for:
data.map(cls => {
    let text = cls.name;
    if (cls.multi_classing.prerequisites.length){
        text += '- Requires ';
        text += cls.multi_classing.prerequisites.map(req => {
            return `${req.minimum_score} ${req.ability_score.name}`
        }).join(', ')
    }
    return (
        <option value={cls.name}>{text}</option>
    )
})

also note that your original outer map function had no return keyword.  easy to miss.
